# Trying to import %m/%d into Rails where no %Y is available in the csv

Tags: csv, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a csv with only the month and date, like this: 08/22, and can't import it into my Rails 4 app. It just gets ignored. I've tried:

```
:birthday =>DateTime.strptime("%m/%d").strftime("%m/%d")

converters: [:date]
```

and a few other things. Is is at all possible to bring a date that has no year into a Rails database?

Comment: Let me add: the year is simply not available to me. I'd be happy with an answer that show me how to input a dummy year, because the year does not matter; it won't be used in the output, which is month and day of a birthday.

Comment: Consider using separate integer fields for the month and date.
Use `numericality` rails validator if you need.

Comment: you could always just format your excel sheet to a date that includes a year. dummy year it to what ever year you and and then use strftime in your app to only display the month and date? ive done that in a previous app where old data did not provide any years and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are the one performing the imports / building the spread sheet, you could format the date field in the excel sheet to a random year, then upload the form with the dummy year but then use strftime in your index, show pages ect to only display the date and month. if year is not important i dont see why this wouldnt work.

I have used this method in the past where my client provided data did not have years attached and it worked for me.

hope this helps.